# Group-ID according to numbering reset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following data:

```
d <- as_tibble(c(1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

The running numbers are one group, and for every reset
I need hvae a new group. What I need is a group-ID for
every numbering reset; hence:

```
d$ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
```

To visualize it:

```
value ID

1   1
2   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
1   3
2   3
3   3
4   3
1   4
2   4
3   4
4   4
5   4
6   4
7   4
```

I have tried using `group_indices` of `dplyr` but
that doesnt do the trick as it groups by same value:

```
d$ID <- d %>% group_indices(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `diff` to subtract the current value with previous value and increment the counter whenever the values are reset.

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(d$value) < 0))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

In `dplyr`,we can use `lag` to compare it with previous value.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% mutate(ID = cumsum(value < lag(value, default = first(value))) + 1)
```

Comment: How to go about it if I have a sequence of characters instead of running numbers:
so c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa")? Here, group_indices again would not work ... thx

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi In that case you can just `data.table::rleid(df$value)` or with `dplyr`, `df%>%
  mutate(ID = cumsum(value != lag(value, default = first(value))) + 1)`